# Недетерминированный конечный автомат (ndfa)

Tags: c++

Кто имел опыт с конечными автоматами, может кусочек структуры показать, который бы на его взгляд показался разумным? Премногим благодарен!

Comment: http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/5301478/Introduction_to_Automata_Theory__Languages__and_Computation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Беглый поиск по интернетам выдаёт вот эту [ссылку](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/31988/) Там человек реализовал DFA, показал классы и их реализацию, и спросил, как это доработать до NDFA. Посмотрите, может натолкнёт на какие-то мысли. 
А вообще попробуйте скачать программу [JFLAP](http://www.jflap.org/) и поиграться там с построением различных автоматов. Погоняйте их по тестам. Это должно помочь в придумывании алгоритма, если Вы именно этого хотите.